# Wordpress https images only get 500 internal server error

Tags: wordpress, image, .htaccess, ssl

I'm trying to publish a new wordpress website on https. The site works except the images don't load. (the site and the media library) I used WP Migrate plugin to migrate the database. All images have https and if I open only the image I get 500 Internal server error (http and https). I tried uploading a new image and the problem is the same. I keep googling on the problem but I haven't found the solution nor the explanation on why images from upload folder served over https are blocked. The logo from theme/images folder loads ok.
Is there something I need to add to htaccess or something in wp-config so the images from upload folder will load?

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: @janh which error log do you mean? I don't have access to server logs..

Comment: I'm not sure if it is alowed but this is the website: https://www.helios-hrvatska.hr/

Comment: Maybe you can ask your provider about them? Have you checked whether there are any extra .htaccess files in any of the directories the images are loaded from? Does your main .htaccess contain anything other than the WP rules? You could also try to create a local copy with XAMPP - if the error happens there too, you can access the logs and see what's wrong.

Comment: @janh the extra .htacess un the upload folder was a good call. Thank you. Now I need to fugure out how to protect the upload folder correctly.